# Internet Computer 0.9.3 y Motoko Problema en localhost:8000 mientras si includo clusterId funciona

Tags: javascript, poo, web

He encontrado un comportamiento extraño en mi aplicacion basica web3.

> Estoy usando ic 0.9.3 y Motoko

Antes de que la aplicacion funcione, me salia un error, lo busque y me decia que actualizara la version de webpack-cli a la 4.10.0

https://bytemeta.vip/repo/dfinity/sdk/issues/2261
Eso "soluciono" el problema. Ya que al entrar en `localhost:8000` respondia con: `Could not find a canister id to forward to`.

Pero si le agregaba el canisterId en la url empezaba a funcionar: `localhost:8000/?canisterId=ryjl3-tyaaa-aaaaa-aaaba-cai`

Alguna idea?

[Codigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxXy2.png)

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kltcl.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoeRl.png)

Edit: he actualizado dfx a 0.11.1 y he intentado cambiar la versión de node a 14 pero nada.

Comment: el codigo no debe subirse en imagenes para eso hay herramientas en la creacion edicion de la pregunta .